# ValueError at --View didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views

I got this error when submitting the form.

> ValueError at /en/checkout/ The view core.views.EnCheckoutView didn't
>   return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

- I double-checked the views.py
- Sometimes after deleting the database file (db.sqlite3): it worked correctly with the same views.py and html template, but after restart computer, the same error comes back again.

and here is its views.py

```
class EnCheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            form = CheckoutForm()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'couponform': CouponForm(),
                'order': order,
                'DISPLAY_COUPON_FORM': True
            }
            shipping_address_qs = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, address_type='S', default=True)
            if shipping_address_qs.exists():
                context.update({
                    'default_shipping_address': shipping_address_qs[0]
                })

            billing_address_qs = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, address_type='B', default=True)
            if billing_address_qs.exists():
                context.update({
                    'default_billing_address': billing_address_qs[0]
                })

            return render(self.request, 'en-checkout-page.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.info(self.request, 'You do not have an active order.')
            return redirect('core:en-checkout')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            if form.is_valid():
                use_default_shipping = form.cleaned_data.get("use_default_shipping")
                if use_default_shipping:
                    print('Using the default shipping address')
                    address_qs = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, address_type='S', customer_name=customer_name, phone=phone, email=email, default=True)
                    if address_qs.exists():
                        shipping_address = address_qs[0]
                        order.shipping_address = shipping_address
                        order.save()
                    else:
                        messages.info(self.request, 'No default shipping address available')
                        return redirect('core:en-checkout')
                else:
                    print('User is entering a new shipping address')
                    customer_name = form.cleaned_data.get('customer_name')
                    phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
                    email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                    shipping_address1 = form.cleaned_data.get('shipping_address')
                    shipping_address2 = form.cleaned_data.get('shipping_address2')
                    shipping_country = form.cleaned_data.get('shipping_country')
                    shipping_zip = form.cleaned_data.get("shipping_zip")
                    if is_valid_form([shipping_address1, shipping_country, shipping_zip]):
                        shipping_address = Address(
                            user=self.request.user,
                            customer_name=customer_name,
                            phone=phone,
                            email=email,
                            street_address=shipping_address1,
                            apartment_address=shipping_address2,
                            country=shipping_country,
                            zip=shipping_zip,
                            address_type='S'
                        )
                        shipping_address.save()
                        order.shipping_address = shipping_address
                        order.save()

                        set_default_shipping = form.cleaned_data.get('set_default_shipping')
                        if set_default_shipping:
                            shipping_address.default = True
                            shipping_address.save()

                    else:
                        messages.info(self.request, 'Please fill in the required shipping address fields')

                use_default_billing = form.cleaned_data.get('use_default_billing')
                same_billing_address = form.cleaned_data.get('same_billing_address')
                if same_billing_address:
                    billing_address = shipping_address
                    billing_address.pk = None
                    billing_address.save()
                    billing_address.address_type = 'B'
                    billing_address.save()
                    order.billing_address = billing_address
                    order.save()
                elif use_default_billing:
                    print('Using the default billing address')
                    address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                        user=self.request.user,
                        address_type='B',
                        default=True
                    )
                    if address_qs.exists():
                        billing_address = address_qs[0]
                        order.billing_address = billing_address
                        order.save()
                    else:
                        messages.info(self.request, 'No default billing address')
                        return redirect('core:checkout')
                else:
                    print('User is entering a new billing address')
                    billing_address1 = form.cleaned_data.get('billing_address')
                    billing_address2 = form.cleaned_data.get('billing_address2')
                    billing_country = form.cleaned_data.get('billing_country')
                    billing_zip = form.cleaned_data.get('billing_zip')

                    if is_valid_form([billing_address1, billing_country, billing_zip]):
                        billing_address = Address(
                            user=self.request.user,
                            street_address=billing_address1,
                            apartment_address=billing_address2,
                            country=billing_country,
                            zip=billing_zip,
                            address_type='B'
                        )

                        billing_address.save()
                        order.billing_address = billing_address
                        order.save()
                        set_default_billing = form.cleaned_data.get('set_default_billing')
                        if set_default_billing:
                            billing_address.default = True
                            billing_address.save()
                    else:
                        messages.info(self.request, 'Please fill in the required billing address fields')

                payment_option = form.cleaned_data.get('payment_option')

                if payment_option == 'S':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='stripe')
                elif payment_option == 'P':
                    return redirect('core:payment', payment_option='paypal')
                else:
                    messages.warning(self.request, 'Invalid payment option selected')
                    return redirect('core:checkout')

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You do not have an active order')
            return redirect('core:en-order-summary')
```

I appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's *waaayyyyy* too much code in you `post()` method - you should extract all the logic to the form's save method, use proper form validation (use modelforms as much as possible), and split it into simple, readable and testable methods.

This being said, your problem is obvious as soon as you extract all the code under the `if form.is_valid()` - there's no `else` branch. So if your form doesn't validate, the function does return `None` indeed.

**EDIT**

> I shall add else right before except..................., right?

You have to add it at the same level as the `if form.is_valid()` - now where it ends up in this plate of spaghettis is beyond my reading abilities, honestly :-/

As a general rule, consider that if you have more than about 20 lines and 2  levels of indentation in a function, then it's probably time to refactor your code. A first obvious refactoring is to move things around to reduce indentation levels. In you case, you can already start by moving the `except` clause right after the only place where it makes sense:

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(self.request, 'You do not have an active order')
        return redirect('core:en-order-summary')

    form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # etc....
```

You already gained one level of indentation (and reduced your try block to the strict minimum so it won't be able to catch another unexpected DoesNotExist exception, should it arise in some code you're calling).

Then make proper use of form validation - here for example:

```
if address_qs.exists():
    shipping_address = address_qs[0]
    order.shipping_address = shipping_address
    order.save()
else:
    messages.info(self.request, 'No default shipping address available')
    return redirect('core:en-checkout')
```

this is plain wrong and *very* rude to your user who will then have to retype everything again. The form itself should validate this. In fact, it shouldn't even show a "use default shipping" option if the user doesn't have a default shipping address yet.

Actually, your view code should really looks like:

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(self.request, 'You do not have an active order')
        return redirect('core:en-order-summary')


    form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST, order=order)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() 
        # this  is supposed to has been validated by the form too
        payment_option = form.get_payment_option()
        return redirect('core:payment', payment_option=payment_option)

    # factor out all the common code creating the context
    # for both get and post in a get_context_data method
    context = self.get_context_data()
    context["form"] = form
    return render(self.request, 'en-checkout-page.html', context)
```

and everything else should be in your form's validation and `save()` method.

Comment: Can you please tell me which else I should delete?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the lines which they should be deleted?

Comment: I repeat: where did I say anything should be deleted ?

Comment: Sorry man! I shall add else right before except..................., right?

Comment: lately, I found out that my checkout form doesn't accept new addresses, only saved ones. My view: